# Finding $\int^{\pi}_{0}f^{-1}(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x+\cos x$, find$$\int^{\pi}_{0}f^{-1}(x) \,\d x.$$

Try: put $x=f(t)$ and $\d x=f'(t) \,\d t$, so
\begin{align*}
\int^{f^{-1}(\pi)}_{f^{-1}(0)}tf'(t) \,\d t &=\int^{f^{-1}(\pi)}_{f^{-1}(0)}t(1-\sin t) \,\d t\\
&= \left.\left(t \cos t-\sin t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)\right|^{f^{-1}(\pi)}_{f^{-1}(0)}.
\end{align*}

Could someone help me how to find $f^{-1}(\pi)$ and $f^{-1}(0)$, thanks.

Comment: @masacroso $f$ is monotonic.

Comment: The answer to the integral looks numerically like being $\pi^2/2$, for what it's worth, but I don't have time to work out why.

Answer (score 7):

Since $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$, we have
$$f(\pi-x)=\pi-f(x).$$ Applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides and replacing $x$ by $f^{-1}(x)$, this gives $$f^{-1}(\pi-x)=\pi-f^{-1}(x).$$
Then, $$\int^\pi_0f^{-1}(\pi-x)\,dx=\int^\pi_0(\pi-f^{-1}(x))\,dx.$$ The substitution $x\to\pi-x$ on the LHS gives
$$\int^\pi_0f^{-1}(x)\,dx=\pi^2-\int^\pi_0f^{-1}(x)\,dx,$$ i.e.
$$\int^\pi_0f^{-1}(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}2,$$ as @Patrick Stevens guessed from numerical calculation in a comment, already.
REMARK: originally, I started with $x_0=f^{-1}(0)$, and found that then, we must have $f^{-1}(\pi)=\pi-x_0$. If we plug both values into the expression given by the OP and use $\sin(\pi-x_0)=\sin x_0$, $\cos x_0=-x_0$ and $\cos(\pi-x_0)=x_0$, it miraculously simplifies to $\pi^2/2$. Thinking about "why?", I came up with the above.

Comment: Nice answer, please check whether my aproach is correct

Answer (score 7):

Using graph and symmetry arguments, we can find the integral. The graph of inverse of $f(x)$ will look like:

[image]

It is now possible to show that the inverse function has a point of symmetry $(\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

The red regions actually cancel out, and green region is half of the rectangle namely $\frac{\pi(\pi-2)}{2}$. The blue region is $\pi$.

So the answer is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Comment: Nice visualisation!

Comment: Actually. I like your answer for not using graph at all.

Comment: The popular vote seems to be divided. Don't be afraid of pictures, though! Famous mathematicians like Littlewood didn't condemn pictures, as long as they can be immediately translated into rigorous text.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the single solution of the equation $\cos t=t$ by $\alpha\ (\approx0.739085)$.

One has $f'(x)=1-\sin x\geq0$ with isolated points of equality. It follows that $f$ is strictly increasing. Furthermore
$$f(-\alpha)=-\alpha+\cos\alpha=0,\quad f(\pi+\alpha)=\pi+\alpha-\cos\alpha=\pi\ .$$
Let $g:=f^{-1}$ be the inverse function of $f$. Then
$$\int_0^\pi g(t)\>dt=\int_{-\alpha}^{\pi+\alpha} g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\>f'(x)\>dx=\int_{-\alpha}^{\pi+\alpha}x f'(x)\>dx\ .$$
Since $f'$ is even with respect to the midpoint ${\pi\over2}$ of the interval of integration we rewrite the first factor in the last integral as ${\pi\over2}+\bigl(x-{\pi\over2}\bigr)$ and obtain
$$\int_{-\alpha}^{\pi+\alpha}x f'(x)\>dx={\pi\over2}\int_{-\alpha}^{\pi+\alpha}f'(x)\>dx={\pi\over2}\bigl(f(\pi+\alpha)-f(-\alpha)\bigr)={\pi^2\over2}\ .$$